# What's the best way to pass props from one page to another in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing some code based on react, here is my requirement:

I wanna submit a form and pass the form to api,
when I summit successfully,
I want to be redirected to another page, and show a message that tells me the form is submit successfully, but in this message, I wanna show the form title (I entered before).

So my question is: what's the best way or better way to pass the field to the new page in React?
I know some ways, like:

1. pass it through route state
2. use context

Is there any other way to do this? And which is recommended in React?
Thanks!

Hope I can get some more suggestions from ReactJs Team, thanks!

Comment: use context is great way if you are working on a bit big project. or you can use redux it's great but it might take some time to learn.

Comment: Passing it through route state is preferred imo. Receive the route state at the other end and use the useEffect hook to show your modal afterwards. One way flow.

In case you need to return to the form page and pre-fill the form fields, you could use the context api. Two way flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redux to store the `formTitleState`

which initially will be an empty string. The state will be  accessible everywhere in your app. You can use the `onchange` event listener to the input field where you are entering the title to change the form title state to whatever you enter in the input. After the post request to the API is successful, use something like

`<Navigate to="/success" />`

from `react-router-dom` to push the user to the other page. Since the `formTitleState` is accessible globally, you can use it in the success page or and show it in the UI.

I hope this helps.